# Unhandled Runtime Error in NextJS, Clerk, and MongoDB project

Tags: next.js, error-handling, runtime-error, unhandled, clerk

My NextJs project was working fine as I was signed in. As soon as signed out, I faced this **Unhandled Runtime Error: Error: Only plain objects, and a few built-ins, can be passed to Client Components from Server Components. Classes or null prototypes are not supported.** PLEASE HELP!

[Image of an error on browser](https://i.stack.imgur.com/6Zvlo.png)

The strange thing is that the error is only occurring when I am trying to sign in from localhost:3000. When I tried opening localhost:3000/image. I successfully got the option to log in.

[Project Structure](https://i.stack.imgur.com/xTllz.png)

[Problematic piece of the code](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ZHNoL.png)

The problem is occurring somewhere around here, because I commented out the parts shown in the image, and I got the home page rendered. No Sign In option though.

Answer (score 0):

AFAICT you are trying to serialize a class instance or null to JSON somewhere in your Next.js code, probably with `JSON.stringify()`, and this is not supported, as per what the error message says.  And this occurs after a timeout expires.

Comment: it has something to do with this piece of code?

https://imgur.com/a/huuIpfn

Comment: Also, when I was signed out and opened localhost:3000 I was getting the error. But when I opened localhost:3000/image (one of the subpage). I perfectly got the login page